# I cannot see the plot of my points in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, points, svd

I am trying to plot a  u vector using the R language.
I have obtained U throught SVD applied to some training data.
I have downloaded the useful library for tm and ggplot2.
I want to plot the 2 dimensions of the vector U , which results from SVD of the Dokument Terms matrix. Which is obtained through my training Data 
here is my code:

```
#Read the training files:
#load the text mining package
library(tm)
library(ggplot2)


#Load the names of the training documents
myfiles = DirSource("C:\\Users\\Sondos\\Downloads\\HW-07-data\\HW-07-data\\training",pattern="^c.*")
#create a corpus and read the files
training=Corpus(myfiles )
# to get an impression of the training object type
training
# to get a deeper look into the documents type
#inspect(training)
#to convert the documents to a document term matrix use
dtm = DocumentTermMatrix(training,control=list(tolower=F))

m = as.matrix(dtm)

s=svd(m)
#store vector U 
k = s$u


plot.new()
points(1:length(k2), k2)
```

The problem is that I cannot see the plot.
Any one has an idea about this?

Comment: See `?plot` or if you want to use `ggplot2`, see `?qplot`.

Comment: welcome to SO! 1) your example is not [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) ; 2) try something around `plot` rather than `plot.new` 3) that's not a `ggplot2`, `tm` or `svd` related problem.

Comment: We don't have access to your hard drive.  Perhaps you could have a look at [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: I did a modification

Comment: why minus 1 :/  .. I am new here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`points` adds points to an existing plot. Try `plot(k2)`.  There should be no need to call `plot.new` explicitly.

Comment: I tried it but nothing appears .even the window of plot can not be seen

Comment: Do you see a plot when you do something simple like `plot(1:5)`?